# Got a nullpoint exception when I use a loop to find an object

Tags: android

I am a rookie in android and I got the next problem.
In one of the activities that I am using, I need an object(Events) that I saved in an ArrayList. Every object that I created I gave it a random ID using UUID.randomUUID(). I use this code to retrieve the specific object that I am looking for

```
private Events mEvent;
  private List<Events> mEvents;
  mEvents = EventLib.get().getEvents(); // With this I rertrieve all the Events from my model
  for(Events event : mEvents){
            if(event.getEventID() == eventId){
                mEvent = event;
            }
        }
```

But the variable mEvent does never initializes. I have debugged the code and the got the list of the id´s that my objects(Events) have, and realize that from the id´s that I get one of them is the one I am looking for, so I don't understand why is it that the "if" condition won't turn to true. Here are the id´s I refer to:

```
E/Event from my list: 20c4ed0c-707f-428f-a67a-ff1ad063a641

E/Event from my list: 6c7f249a-8168-421e-a8eb-a32f0f09c256

E/Event from my list: cbb9adc2-33a5-4b50-9d18-649833ae2e70

E/Event from my list: 5d21362c-d67f-4e36-9cf3-0baac6379962

E/Event from my list: 7eb70b0a-b070-45f1-8ed8-0cd6728fdf86

E/Event looking for: 7eb70b0a-b070-45f1-8ed8-0cd6728fdf86
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if (event.getEventID().equals(eventId)) {
   ...
}
```

When comparing strings you should use `equals()` instead of `==`.  See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/) for more info.

Comment: @RicardoHerrera great!  don’t forget to mark this as the answer then